# Why can't I access to a UserControl custom property inside a Repeater?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, user-controls, repeater

I'm doing a Data Binding for a Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAlumni" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptAlumni_DataBinding">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc1:AlumnoBox runat="server" ID="AlumnoBox" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected void rptAlumni_DataBinding(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (UserControl)e.Item.FindControl("AlumnoBox");
}
```

but I can't do `item.MyCustomID` for example, I can't see that property. Instead, if I move the UserControl outside the Repeater and I do `AlumnoBox.MyCustomID` inside the Page Load it works as well.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  `UserControl` inherits from `UserControl` but you have added addtional properties like `MyCustomID`. Of course you can't access those properties if you cast to `UserControl` since the base class does not know them. Instead cast to the right type `AlumnoBox`:

```
var item = (context_box_AlumnoBox) e.Item.FindControl("AlumnoBox"); 
int id = item.MyCustomID;
```

Comment: I can't do `(AlumnoBox)e.Item.FindControl("AlumnoBox")`. It doesn't know that `AlumnoBox` type (since it's just the name of the UserControl).

Comment: @markzzz: then use the correct name of that type. You have somewhere created this `UserControl`,  look at the codebehind class, there you find the name of it.

Comment: That's the correct name of that type :) `<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AlumnoBox.ascx.cs" Inherits="context_box_AlumnoBox" %>` and `public partial class context_box_AlumnoBox : System.Web.UI.UserControl`

Comment: It says I'm missing "using" or some "assembly" :O I've just create it using Visual Studio...

Comment: @markzzz: use `context_box_AlumnoBox`. I have edited it